# Action name declared but not found

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, action

This is one part of my `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "DefaultApi",
  routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}"
);
```

This is the part in my controller `BaseController.cs` where I declared `ActionName` (edit: I have another class `CustomersController.cs` that inherits `BaseController.cs`):

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Get")]
public List<T> Get() {
  return baseBL.Get();
}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Count")]
public int Count() {
  return baseBL.Count();
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Insert")]
public int Insert(T entity) {
  return baseBL.Insert(entity);
}

[HttpPut]
[ActionName("Update")]
public int Update(T entity) {
  return baseBL.Update(entity);
}

[HttpDelete]
[ActionName("Delete")]
public int Delete(Guid entityID) {
  return baseBL.Delete(entityID);
}
```

This is the part in the query where I called the `DELETE` method:

```
try {
  $.ajax({
    url: me.FrmDetail.mainurl + "/Delete",
    method: "DELETE",
    data: JSON.stringify($(jtem).text()),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset = utf-8',
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

This is the error returned after calling it:

> Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51070/Customers/Delete'.
>   MessageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'Customers' that matches the request."

I'm trying several solutions I found on Stackoverflow but it's still bugged (i.e. changing IISExpress config file).

Comment: It says you are trying to call http://localhost:51070/Customers/Delete but your controller is named BaseController.cs can you show your CustomersController please

Comment: Does your `CustomersController` extend the `BaseController`? `public class CustomersController : BaseController`

Comment: It is really not much, BaseController is inherited by CustomersController. I will add it to the post.